# Java Generics type safety

Tags: java

I once read that Java Generics brings the type safety that was previously missed with handling Object references and including explicit casts by making all casts *implicit* and *automatic*. I studied Generics and understand its mechanics, but I still can't see how automatically generated implicit casts brings type safety over explicit casts that were used prior to Generics - I mean, I still could use explicit casts and achieve the same effect.. ?

Generics seems to have simply streamlined the process by taking what had been a sole programming approach on the programmer's side and make into a feature of the language, simplifying the process by really handling/adjusting code for the programmer..?

Comment: Airbags and seatbelts make cars safer.  Of course you could not wear the seatbelt and disable the airbag - is that what you are saying?

Comment: What I'm saying is, the alleged type safety seems to be achievable without Generics, and the only benefit Generics seems to have brought is write down the lore of programming practices into a feature of the language that can be accessed easily via a few new syntactic elements of the language, that is, nothing really new like new levels of type safety..

Answer (score 4):

> but I still can't see how automatically generated implicit casts
>   brings type safety over explicit casts that were used prior to
>   Generics -

You have not a automatically generated implicit cast (downcast) in raw types, you have to explicit cast from `Object` to a specific type as a raw type can take any `Object` and the problem is there.

For example here you don't have type safety as **you can put anything in a List that functionally should contain only `String`** :

```
List listOfString = new ArrayList();
listOfString.add("myString"); // compile 
listOfString.add(5); // compile (not a String)
String expectedStringButNot = (String) listOfString.get(1); // ClassCastException at runtime
```

With generics, you have type safety as **you could not put anything in  a List that functionally should contain only `String`** as the compiler will stop before :

```
List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<>();
listOfString.add("myString"); // compile 
listOfString.add(5); // doesn't compile (not a String)
```

Comment: Thanks. But then there is really nothing new in that, and it shows how Generics merely enforces type safety (to a degree, I guess) rather than provide something that was previously unattainable. In your examples above, careful programming would produce the same effect without the need for Generics interfering to prevent pitfalls..

Comment: You are welcome. I understand your point. But why not benefiting from a careful programming feature provided by your compiler ?
Even good developers may do mistake by error and for less good of them, it is still more frequent.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: indeed, generics are in fact designed to provide additional compile-time checking. Stronger than that, generic types are erased at runtime. They provide no additional "functionality" to Java itself.

Generic kind of 'replaced' some casts that were needed when generic weren't there.

```
// My list of strings
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hello");
String str1 = list.get(0); // Won't work
String str2 = (String) list.get(0);
```

The compiler was simply not sure that the list only contained String object, although the programmer was sure he only put Strings in it.

```
// My list of strings
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // <> means <String> in this case
list.add("Hello");
String str1 = list.get(0); // works
String str2 = (String) list.get(0); // The typecast is unnecessary,
                                    // for the compiler already knows
                                    // that the list could only contain
                                    // strings
```

So in the first code snippet, the typecast to `String` was necessary because you simply got an `Object` from the list. In the second snippet however, the typecast is made unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Set<String> st = map.keySet(); // This will only contain String objects
```

In this example it ensures that `st` will only contain String objects. This reduces the possibility of run time errors due casting.

Additionally

```
Set<String> st = new Set<String>();
st.add("a");  // allowed
st.add('a');  // compile time error
```

Here the compile time error will identify the problem, so hours debugging can be avoided.