# Why are generics needed when we can do casting to Object class?

Tags: java, object, generics

We have generics in java using which we can generalize a class.
I know that Object class is the parent class of every class.

When I can typecast to and from Object then why generics are needed?

```
class Response<T>{
    T data;
}
```

```
class Response{
    Object data;
}
```

Both of the above code snippets will work the same way.

Comment: Type safety. And you no longer have to cast.

Comment: I'd read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841156/java-generics-type-safety)

Comment: Also related, "why use Java (x >=5) when you can stay with Java 4?" Jokes aside, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java).

Comment: Generics allow you to find issues during compilation and not by observing `ClassCastException` during runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make a list in the "pre-generic" way and do something terrible like this. The result is I can't know the type of the object I get from the list without resorting to reflection.

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add(new Integer(1));
myList.add(new Cat());

Object whatIsThis = myList.get(1);
```

With generics, I can say

```
List<Cat> myList = new ArrayList();    
myList.add(new Cat());
myList.add(new Integer(1));  // compile time error
myList.add(new Dog()); // compile time error

Cat whatIsThis = myList.get(1); // I *know* this must be a Cat
```

Answer (score 4):

That's how things were done before generics existed: you declared objects of type `Object` when you didn't know their specific type.

But an `Object` type doesn't say much, the benefit of generics is that now we *know* what's the type of the object, as far as it's possible at compile time. Read about [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to understand the limitations of the way Generics were implemented in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Casting(Boxing and Unboxing) is an expensive run-time operation. Generics incur no run-time overhead.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Boxing and unboxing still happens at run-time. And generics still require a cast at runtime, it's only that you don't have to write it explicitly.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, I have "corrected" the answer. From your link: "The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods." The point of the answer was performance and type safety is better with generics. The compiler will resort to `Object` only when the " if the type parameters are unbounded", and thus require casts.